# How to compare two date and time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 dates and time, for this, I am getting data in timestamp and I convert timestamp in date but now how can I compare it?

```
exp time:  1580109819

expD:  Mon Jan 27 2020 12:53:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

newDateTime:  Mon Jan 27 2020 11:54:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

this.logData.exp = 1580109819;
console.log("exp time: ", this.logData.exp);
var expD = new Date(this.logData.exp * 1000);
console.log("expD: ", expD);
console.log(expD.getDate() + '-' + (expD.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + expD.getFullYear() + ' ' + expD.getTime());

var currentD = new Date(this.logData.exp * 1000);
let dateString = currentD.toUTCString();
console.log(dateString);
let newDateTime = new Date()
console.log("newDateTime: ", newDateTime);
```

Comment: Check [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to handle dates.

Comment: Keep your data as timestamp only and convert your date also to timestamp it makes easy for comparison

Answer (score 4):

You can save those date strings as Date objects.

So below code in the comparison to Two dates with **Javascript**.

```
  var currentDate = new Date("2020-01-27");
  var pastDate = new Date("2020-01-20");


  if (pastDate < currentDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 30);
  }

  $scope.pastDate = pastDate;
  $scope.currentDate = currentDate;
```

Answer (score 3):

using [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/), for example:

```
var date = moment("2013-03-24")
var now = moment();

if (now > date) {
   // date is past
} else {
   // date is future
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

```
currentD.getTime() > newDateTime.getTime()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare it as **timestamps**, without converting into `Date` object.

Assuming `this.logData` is already in timestamp (seconds), converting it into milli seconds for comparison.

New date is created using date object constructor and then converted into timestamp using method, `getTime()`.

```
// For converting into milli seconds.
const expDateTimestamp = this.logData.exp * 1000;

// New date timestamp
const newDateTime = new Date();
const newDateTimeStamp = newDateTime.getTime();

// Comparison
if (expDateTimestamp < newDateTimeStamp) {

} else {

}
```